# ERROR 1452 : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1452

Help me please!

I am having this error.

```
Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (world.alarmes, CONSTRAINT fk_alarmes_registos1 FOREIGN KEY (idRegisto) REFERENCES registos (idRegisto) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I have these tables.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `registos` (
  `data_registo` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `hora_registo` time NOT NULL,
  `idSensor` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Temperatura` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Humidade` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pt_orvalho` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idRegisto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRegisto`,`idSensor`,`data_registo`,`hora_registo`),
  KEY `fk_registos_sensores1_idx` (`idSensor`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_registos_sensores1` FOREIGN KEY (`idSensor`) REFERENCES `sensores` (`idSensor`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) 




CREATE TABLE `alarmes` (
  `idAlarme` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao_alarme` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_criacao` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `idRegisto` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAlarme`,`idRegisto`),
  KEY `fk_alarmes_registos1_idx` (`idRegisto`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_alarmes_registos1` FOREIGN KEY (`idRegisto`) REFERENCES `registos` (`idRegisto`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

When I do an insert into the table records the error pops up.

```
insert into registos values ('2014-03-31', '14:03:32', 'BrgTH032', '22.3', '45.3', '9.9', '32');
```

If I do this:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

the next insertion already accepted, but when I try again. back to give the same error.

I've been researching and fails  because the registos table references a foreign key from the sensores table. You can't directly insert into a relational table without there being a corresponding entry in the table that is being referenced.

But I don't know how to resolve this.

Help me please.

-------EDIT( I used a trigger to populate the table Alarmes)------------------------

```
DELIMITER $$
create TRIGGER alerta
BEFORE INSERT ON registos
FOR EACH ROW
begin
Set @tempmax=0;
Set @tempmin=0;


select lim_inf_temp, lim_sup_temp into @tempmin, @tempmax from sensores  where idSensor=NEW.idSensor;


Set @maxidAlarme=0;
if (CAST(NEW.Temperatura AS UNSIGNED)<@tempmin) then
SELECT MAX(idAlarme) into @maxidAlarme FROM alarmes;
SET @maxidAlarme=@maxidAlarme+1;
INSERT INTO alarmes(idAlarme,descricao_alarme, idRegisto) VALUES (@maxidAlarme,"temperatura inserida inferior ao normal",New.idRegisto);
end if; 


if (CAST(NEW.Temperatura AS UNSIGNED)>@tempmax) then
SELECT MAX(idAlarme) into @maxidAlarme FROM alarmes;
SET @maxidAlarme=@maxidAlarme+1;
INSERT INTO alarmes(idAlarme,descricao_alarme, idRegisto) VALUES (@maxidAlarme,"temperatura inserida superior ao normal",New.idRegisto);
end if; 

end $$;

DELIMITER  ;
```

Comment: Do you have an entry in table Sensores with an idSensor = 'BrgTH032' ?

Comment: What i'm supossed to do?

Comment: 'BrgTH032', check that the  'Sensores' table with an idSensor of 'BrgTH032' matches **exactly** character for character. Particulary zero and not the letter 'O'. And that letter case matches exactly. Also, put the column names in your insert query as the order of values may not match exactly with your table definition.

Comment: Thanks for reply. idSensor of 'BrgTH032' matches exactly character for character in table sensores and table registos. In my opinion has nothing to do with the sensors table, but honestly do not know why I'm not working and I really needed help.

Comment: "the next insertion already accepted, but when I try again. back to give the same error." What are the values that you attempt to insert the next time? What error do you get?

Comment: I try to insert the same value. It work's because Temporarily disabling referential constraints (set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS to 0)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert more values into the table than allowed 7 (seven) but 6 (six) expected.

Please, **always** include the columns that you are inserting to in an 'insert' query.

There are **seven columns** in this table but one is an **'auto increment' column** so there should be **6 (six) values** in the insert query.

```
CREATE TABLE `registos` (
  `data_registo` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `hora_registo` time NOT NULL,
  `idSensor` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Temperatura` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Humidade` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pt_orvalho` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idRegisto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRegisto`,`idSensor`,`data_registo`,`hora_registo`),
  KEY `fk_registos_sensores1_idx` (`idSensor`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_registos_sensores1
```

Here is the 'insert' query:

```
insert into registos values ('2014-03-31', '14:03:32', 'BrgTH032', '22.3', '45.3', '9.9', '32');
```

There are **seven** values but you would expect the query to look like (columns added):

```
insert into registos (data_registo, hora_registo, idSensor, Temperatura, Humidade, pt_orvalho)
values ('2014-03-31', '14:03:32', 'BrgTH032', '22.3', '45.3', '9.9', '32');
```

I suggest that the query should be:

```
insert into registos (data_registo, hora_registo, idSensor, Temperatura, Humidade, pt_orvalho)
values ('2014-03-31', '14:03:32', 'BrgTH032', '22.3', '45.3', '9.9');
```

The trigger on 'registos' must be an **after insert** trigger to pick up the NEW 'idRegisto' value.

```
create TRIGGER alerta
AFTER INSERT ON registos
FOR EACH ROW
begin
```

Comment: The last value is the idRegisto :S

Comment: idRegisto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT : means that it will be automatically generated when the record is added to the database. You **must not**  include that in your query. I will amend my answer to show what the query should be.

Comment: Thanks for reply...I try without idRegisto and give me same error :(

Comment: I use a trigger to poppulate the table alarmes.  Is it that she's shooting me the error?

Comment: Ah, drat, that complicates things! For now disable that trigger and let us see if the insert into  registos works! Then we can start to sort out the trigger. ;-/ And, yes, the fault could well be from the trigger.

Comment: If the insert don't shoot trigger works, if shoot doesn't work. because the trigger poppulate table alarmes with a fk (idRegisto) from table registos...

Comment: I hope you undersant my explanation :S

Comment: Yes, just make your trigger an 'after insert' on the row and pick up the id from the NEW value in the trigger.

Comment: I edit my question with the trigger code, do you think it is well made that ​​trigger?

Comment: thanks for help. It's very usefull. You can edit your answer and leave only the trigger. Thanks again